# In Azure DevOps, Test Manager can be assign to Basic access level?

Tags: azure-devops

As per below link, test manager in AzureDevOps cannot be assigned to Stakeholder level access.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#pricing

So it can be assign to basic access level with contributor permission? Please clarify on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally possible. We have such cases in one of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

For using Test Manager you need to buy different licenses, you buy them from the link you provided and everyone can use Test Manager that have license. Basic access to azure devops does not include access to Test Manager

Comment: Correct you do need to buy the Test Manager extension, but this extension can be applied to Basic subscribers (and not to Stakeholders) to give this functionality.